# Deploy zip artifact from another build action to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

Is it possible to deploy arbitrary zip archive artifacts to Nexus through Maven as snapshots?

We have a build step that is not supported through any application-specific Maven plugin.  Instead, our full build and deployment process is as follows:

1) Maven POM compiles the Java component of the build, using Jenkins.
2) Shell script calls create a deployable artifact shell scripts were wrapped around calling a code generation application, which are then zipped up into an archive by the application itself.  I need these artifacts deployed to Nexus as both snapshots, and as releases as appropriate.

I tried using the maven-assembly-plugin however this assumes that the plugin itself is creating the zip archive, not simply deploying an archive that was produced by some other method.

I would prefer to do this within Maven since our Nexus settings and credentials are already within the environment and do not need to be passed manually on the command line.  Using the Nexus UI for this is not a viable option since this needs to be part of a standard build-deploy-test process, which may happen many times per day, for a couple dozen applications.

Comment: What about using the maven-deploy-plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'm answering my own question (oh bother...)

I resolved this issue by using the **maven-assembly-plugin**, which allows you to define arbitrary artifacts, and deploy them (snapshots or releases) to Nexus.  The assembly plugin uses a bill of materials (src.xml) that defines the exact contents of the artifact (either including or excluding files, directories, changing file permissions, etc).  This can also be used for creating Java uber jars, but it appears that using the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) is the preferred method for creating uber jars.

[Maven Assembly Plugin main webpage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)